# How to assert some Java method is garbage free?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a piece of code that (currently) use Java 8’s Optional and Stream. And we started having GC overhead issues since this code was deployed to production. See the gist of the code below (getters, constructors and overloads removed for clarity):

```java
class DynamicFilter extends org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.AbstractFilter {

  private Config config;

  @Override
  public Result filter (LogEvent event) {
    Level threshold = config.threshold (event);

    return event.getLevel ().isMoreSpecificThan (threshold) ? onMatch : onMismatch;
  }

}

class Config {

  private Level defaultLevel;

  private List<Overwrite> overwrite;

  public Level threshold (LogEvent log) {
    return overwrites.stream ()
      .filter (o -> o.match (log))
      .findFirst ()
      .map (Overwrite::getThreshold)
      .orElse (defaultLevel);
  }

}

class Overwrite {

  private Level threshold;

  private List<Predicate<LogEvent>> conditions;

  public boolean match (LogEvent log) {
    return conditions.stream ()
      .allMatch (c -> c.test (log));
  }

}
```

While it could be unrelated, I’d like to make this code garbage free, especially since it’s a code ran inside every log statement. This shouldn’t be very hard using for loops and if statements, but is there a way I can assert I didn’t forgot some nasty object allocation? Eg. an int gets autoboxed?

TLDR: Is there a way for me to write a unit test like:

```java
memory.startRecording ();
myCode.run ();
memory.assertNoCallToNewInCurrentThreadSinceRecordingStarted ();
```

### PS

Disabling this code in production did not solve the GC overhead issues. I keep this question open because I believe being able to assert some piece of code doesn’t do any allocation can be useful to future readers, but I don’t need it at the moment.

Comment: What if you add an `int` to a list and it gets auto boxed? What happens to `String`s that may get put into the string pool?

Comment: And what you may mean is "allocation free" not "gc free" since the latter term does not make any sense, the garbage collection just runs no matter what.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly the kind of thing I want to ensure isn’t happening.

Comment: @luk2302 I used the term "GC free" because that’s how the people doing Log4J calls it. But you’re right, I’m not talking about disabling GC.

Comment: I seriously doubt this will get you anywhere because there will most likely be tons of allocations and collections happening in your code unless your code is literally `int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`. E.g. `Optional.of`, `Arrays.stream`, ... they all allocated stuff. Instead you should analyze the heap during / after execution and look for anomalies.

Comment: 1) "especially since it’s a code ran inside every log statement" - can you show that code actually? 2) " int gets autoboxed" - you would need _a lot_ of these to trigger the behavior that you are talking about... do you have GC logs enabled to see where that might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread in JVM maintain allocation counter, counting bytes allocated since thread creation.
You can use this counter to measure amount of allocation done by piece of code (though it should run in parent thread).

Below is the snippet of code I usually use for that purpose.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class MemMeter {

    private static long OFFSET = measure(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    });

    /**
     * @return amount of memory allocated while executing provided {@link Runnable}
     */
    public static long measure(Runnable x) {
       long now = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();
       x.run();
       long diff = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() - now;
       return diff - OFFSET;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private static long getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() {
        return ((com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()).getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://blog.ragozin.info/2016/09/how-to-measure-object-size-in-java.html) you can find more details on this topic.